# How to get avro schema from schema registry by subject?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I have the Schema Registry on localhost:8083 and want to get the avro schema "test.data" by name to use elsewhere.

When I try

```
$ curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8083/subjects?subject=test.data'
```

I get back all schemas in the registry.

Is there a way to get one schema by name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give a try to :

```
curl 'http://localhost:8083/subjects/test.data/versions/latest' | jq '.schema'
```